# Formatting a string in Arabic (Swift)

Tags: swift, string, formatting, arabic

I need to format the string so that if the user has Arabic in the tinctures, the order of phrases in the string does not change. The problem is that if there is an Arabic line, swift changes the order of phrases when formatting.

**Initial data:**

```
let string = "%1$@ - %2$d"
let arguments = [
    اللغة,
    10000
]
```

**If I use:**

```
String(format: string, arguments: arguments)
```

*I get:* `اللغة - 10000` (but I need the number to be on the right)

**If I use:**

```
String(format: string, locale: Locale(identifier: "en_US"), arguments: arguments)
```

*I get:* `(string) - 10,000` (but I need the number not to be divided into groups)

How can I get such a string: `(string) - 10000`?

Comment: You can add the opposite format to Arabic localized strings file: `"%2$d - %1$@"`

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this:

1. Start the string with U+202A LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING
2. Then add U+2067 RIGHT-TO-LEFT ISOLATE
3. Then add your Arabic text
4. End your left-to-right text with U+2069 POP DIRECTIONAL ISOLATE
5. Add the rest of your string

So

```swift
let string = "\u{202a}\u{2067}اللغة\u{2069} - 10000"
```